# where is product.list_price point to / declared?

Tags: odoo-14

```
@api.depends('list_price', 'price_extra')
@api.depends_context('uom')
def _compute_product_lst_price(self):
    to_uom = None
    if 'uom' in self._context:
        to_uom = self.env['uom.uom'].browse(self._context['uom'])

    for product in self:
        if to_uom:
            list_price = product.uom_id._compute_price(product.list_price, to_uom)
        else:
            list_price = product.list_price
        product.lst_price = list_price + product.price_extra
```

on odoo product.product i dont see list_price field. but on code i find
product.list_price. where is product.list_price point to / declared ?

Comment: `product.product` inherits `product.template` where `list_price` is declared.

Comment: Is this python? If so, the [tag:python] should be included.